# Is it necessary to flush a QTextStream before closing a QFile?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I need to log some text messages to a file with following requirements :

1. Each text messages is written in a new line at the end of the file.
2. Be reasonably sure that each message was correctly written to the file.

So far, the function is using `QTextStream` and `QFile`:

```
bool FileManager::appendLine(const QString &line)
{
    if(!m_file.open(QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text)) // m_file is a QFile
        return false;

    QTextStream ts(&m_file);

    ts << line << endl;

    bool status = (ts.status() == QTextStream::Ok);

    m_file.close();

    return status;
}
```

Point 1 is satisfied but i have doubts about Point 2.

Even Qt Doc says that it is sufficient to `close()` the QFile to flush all its internal buffers :

> void QFileDevice::close()
>
> Reimplemented from QIODevice::close().
>
> Calls QFileDevice::flush() and closes the file. Errors from flush are ignored.

What about the internal buffer of the QTextStream ?

Is it necessary to call `QTextStream::flush()` before closing the file ?

About Point 2, i guess that reading back the line just after it has been written would be the only way to be 100% sure of that. (for example a power failure may occur while the kernel has still datas in its buffers )

Thanks.

Comment: For the textstream,  `flush()` is unnecessary, it is done with `endl`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, its not, because you are appending `&endl` in each write!

- Writting `&endl` to the QTextStream writes '\n' to the stream and ***flushes*** the stream. It is Equivalent to: `stream << '\n' << flush;`
- Further, when QTextStream is flushed due to `&endl`,  it will empty all data from its write buffer into the device and call `flush()` on the device.

Comment: Indeed, i missed it in Qt's Doc. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

While this **particular** code will work because operations with `QTextStream` end with an `endl`, it's still better to ensure that `QTextStream` is completely and utterly finished working with the file when you close it. Just use scopes.

```
bool FileManager::appendLine(const QString &line)
{
    if(!m_file.open(QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text)) // m_file is a QFile
        return false;
    
    bool status {false};
    {
        QTextStream ts(&m_file);
        
        ts << line << endl;
        
        status = (ts.status() == QTextStream::Ok);
    }
    
    m_file.close();
    
    return status;
}
```